# Technical meaning of "profinite circle"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, terminology, math-history, topos-theory

In a private exchange with a professional mathematician, I found the following statement:

the "small etale topos" of a finite field is a "profinite circle", and thus looks like circle.

Could anyone explain me the exact meaning of "profinite circle" in this (or any other) context? And please do not tell me to ask him about it, since I have only very occasional access to him.

Thanks

PS: Apparently, Proposition 8.1 in Chapter 5 of the following text by Grothendiek deals is what is at stake here:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206203v2.pdf

Comment: It doesn't really have a precise meaning. I suppose here it alludes to the fact that the fundamental group is $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, which is the profinite completion of the fundamental group of the circle (which is $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: @Zhen Lin. Ok, then my question would be: What does "profinite" mean in all those contexts? What is the difference to just "finite"? I am sorry, but I do not understand the term.

Comment: That does have a precise meaning. You can start by looking up profinite groups.

Comment: @Zhen Lin. Is a profinite circle a profinite group? If so, of which kind?

Comment: No, it is not a profinite group. It is not really anything at all, actually.

Comment: @Zhen Lin. Then, wh should a professional mathematician say that? I just quoted above the statement, and I just would like some clarification.....

Comment: It is an evocative phrase. To people who know at least something about the subject, it suggests the right idea without going into technical details. But if you don't know anything at all, then it doesn't really convey anything.

Comment: @ZhenLin Which would be that right idea, if I may ask?

Comment: I explained that in my first comment: we _might_ think of the small étale topos of a finite field as a profinite circle because its fundamental group is $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: @Zhen Lin. Ok, now I get it, Sorry for annoying you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as a group $G$ defines a homotopy type $BG$, its [classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space), a [profinite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group) defines a [profinite homotopy type](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profinite+homotopy+type), and "profinite circle" refers to the [étale homotopy type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_homotopy_type) of $\text{Spec } \mathbb{F}_q$, which is the profinite homotopy type $B \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, where $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the profinite group of [profinite integers](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Profinite_completion_of_the_integers). This is the [absolute Galois group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Galois_group) of $\mathbb{F}_q$, or equivalently the [étale fundamental group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_fundamental_group) of $\text{Spec } \mathbb{F}_q$.

The sense in which this looks like a circle is that the circle, as a homotopy type, is $B \mathbb{Z}$. The simplest version of this relationship is the claim that the category of finite connected covering spaces of the circle is equivalent to the opposite of the category of finite extensions of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: Would it be fair to intuitively say that that "circle" is pretty much the orbit of the identity of a singular point?

Comment: @Javier: I don't know what you mean by "orbit," "identity," or "singular point" in that sentence.

Comment: Have a look at this (the slide at 1:14:30). That is the kind of visualization I have in mind, which is somehow meant for a point defined over a finite field Fp. That is very much like a point orbitating, if you want.